# What is the amount of memory used in dokku mongodb service?

Tags: mongodb, memory, digital-ocean, dokku

I am used to using mlab for mongodb. Recently I started exploring the dokku mongodb instance.

In case of mlab it is clearly stated the size of Database offered. 
How do I find this in the case of using a dokku service.

Say I am using a 5$ droplet in digital ocean. what will size of database be in this droplet as opposed to 10$ droplet.

Or will the container expand as much as possible.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it appears to be a question for [digital ocean support.](https://www.digitalocean.com/company/contact/)

Comment: @NeilLunn  No this is a general question. I only used digital ocean as an example. You can see the title has no references to digital ocean in it. you can replace it with any service you like.

Comment: Have to disagree with you there. The moment you start talking about 5$ and 10$ you are actually asking about "services from a provider", and that's basically "off-topic" for here.